# Cloud Code Parameters and Results

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm making an iOS app using swift and am using a cloud backend for the first time, namely Parse.com. I am curious what I can pass as parameters to cloud code functions and then receive as a return value. I want to send an array of PFObjects and also return an array of them, but I get the error `Caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException" with reason "PFObjects are not allowed here."` I am thinking of instead sending an array of dictionaries of the values I need to send and then return the same way. Can I do it this way, or is there another, better way to do this?

Comment: You can only send/receive what the Parse API allows. For example, `-getObjectInBackgroundWithId:` will only ever get you one PFObject, because that's its return type. Similarly, `-findObjectsInBackground` returns an array. PFObject has `-saveInBackground` to save one and `+saveAllInBackground:` (note it's a class method) to save multiple.

Comment: @Michael I'm talking about saving and receiving PFObjects to and from cloud code functions though, not saving and fetching objects.

Comment: What do you mean by "to and from cloud code functions"? What are these functions, if not functions in the Parse API? And what difference do you see in "saving and fetching objects", when those objects are PFObjects since you're using Parse. It would help if you include your code and the line that's giving you an error.

Comment: @Michael Here is Parse's documentation on it https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide Unfortunately it does not say much about parameter and return types and after searching the internet a bit I did not find what I was looking for anywhere.

Comment: Now I understand what you're saying. The PFCloud class reference shows the parameter is a dictionary, but doesn't go into any detail. The expectation though is that you could only pass things that can be serialised, and therefore they probably need to conform to NSCoding. You could send an array of objectIds.

Comment: @Michael I've seen that suggested but that would not work for me because I am trying to send objects that have not been saved yet that will be saved by the cloud code function if certain conditions are met, but it is not practical to check these conditions client-side because there would be a large amount of data I would have to receive from the server.

Comment: The source code (https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/blob/master/Parse/Internal/PFEncoder.m) shows what you can send. Since it supports NSData, you could look into using NSCoding to archive your PFObjects. A quick Google of "archive PFObject" shows some have had success with it.